# How to run pnacl app in Internet Explorer

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, google-nativeclient

I need to run an existing chrome native client app in "Internet Explorer". How can I achieve that?
It uses OpenCV and c++ for video processing. I tried it on chrome and it works fine.

Is there any changes I have to make in my existing app or any plugging I need for IE in order to run it?
Or can i just try to run it within internet explorer?

Also which specific versions of IE supports the native-client.
How to get this work?

Any other issues I might encounter if I used internet explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer doesn't support Native Client.

Comment: Can't i use pnacl within internet explorer using google chrome frame.

Comment: Chrome Frame was deprecated in 2013 because its original intent (bring modern web features to IE) isn't necessary now that IE updates regularly and supports modern web features: http://www.google.com/chromeframe/about/